# How to Stretch Video Vegas Movie Studio

Tags: video, video-editor, vegas-pro, aspect

So I filmed with my Go Pro with a Stretched screen for 16:9 when I resized it to get everything. Is there a way to stretch the video instead of moving the camera to adjust to the 4:3 the video is in a the moment?

I am using VEGAS Movie Studio 15.0 Platinum

If there is another way I can do things that is more efficient I would like to know what as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a third option which is to stretch the 16:9 event to be taller so that it matches the 4:3 ratio. This must be done at the Track level. Open up **Track Motion** and disable **Lock Aspect Ratio** and resize the 16:9 media to fill the 4:3 frame. Everything will be tall and thin but there will be no black bars from letterboxing and no loss of picture data from cropping. (i think it looks bad but some people watch TV like this all the time)

https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/24/976641#976651